# Connect With PostgreSQL in Phalcon Framework

Tags: postgresql, phalcon

Phalcon is not able to connect to postgrsql. Here are my settings in config.php

```
return new \Phalcon\Config(array(
    'database' => array(
        'adapter'     => 'Postgresql',
        'host'        => 'localhost',
        'username'    => 'postgres',
        'password'    => 'root',
        'dbname'      => 'mydb',
        'charset'     => 'utf8',
    ),
    'application' => array(
        'controllersDir' => __DIR__ . '/../../app/controllers/',
        'modelsDir'      => __DIR__ . '/../../app/models/',
        'viewsDir'       => __DIR__ . '/../../app/views/',
        'pluginsDir'     => __DIR__ . '/../../app/plugins/',
        'libraryDir'     => __DIR__ . '/../../app/library/',
        'cacheDir'       => __DIR__ . '/../../app/cache/',
        'baseUri'        => '/test/',
    )
));
```

> Page is blank showing no errors.

DI service implementation

```
use Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Postgresql as DbAdapter;

$di->set('db', function () use ($config) {
    return new DbAdapter(array(
        'host' => $config->database->host,
        'username' => $config->database->username,
        'password' => $config->database->password,
        'dbname' => $config->database->dbname,
        "charset" => $config->database->charset
    ));
});
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Ok but config is not enough. Give us your `$di->db` service implementation and usage case. Also at least some errors should be shown too.

Comment: add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in index.php. Also you need to change the DbAdapter to `Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Postgresql`. Also we need to see how your services are set up.

Comment: Use the phalcon debugger (without try-catch in public/index.php) and show us the error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no **port** in db connection array you used. Default postgresql port is **5432**. so use this in your db connection and try to pass array directly to postgresql adapter constructor. 
or 
install postgres pdo /php pdo again.

Answer (score 0):

I think that code is fine.
I was working a project where i had to use MySQL and PostGres.I connected my Postgresdb by following-

Below default 'db' connection string i wrote the following code inside services.php-

```
$di->setShared('pgphalcon', function () {
$config = $this->getConfig();
$adaptar = "PostgreSQL";
$class = 'Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\\' . $adaptar;
$params = [
    'host'     => "localhost",
    'port'     => "5432", // for localhost no need to put this line unless u change the port
    'username' => "postgres",
    'password' => "12345",
    'dbname'   => "phalcon",

];
$connection = new $class($params);
return $connection;
```

});

Then your controller function

do the following-

```
public function yourcontrollernameAction()
{

   $con = $this->di->get('pghalcon');
   $post = $con->fetchOne("SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", Phalcon\Db::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $this->view->data= $post;

}
```

For better Understanding I'd like to suggest visit this [url](https://phalcon-php-framework-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.0/api/Phalcon_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Postgresql.html)

One thing to clarify- I was failed to do db operation by Model for PostGreSQL. That's why I used this way.